# Not found resource in controller web api Uri with .json

Tags: c#, json, rest, api

I need to run a REST query request to a Web API controller using the following format:

```
http://path/name.json?foo.bar.text=aCertainValue
```

(I cannot change this format since it depends on external providers).

The problem I have is that I cannot retrieve the query result.

I have tried the following options on my server code (written in C#):

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(Name = "name.json")]
public List<SpaceFound3rdParty> findRes([FromUri (Name = "foo.bar.text")] string text)
{...}
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("name.json")]
public List<SpaceFound3rdParty> findRes([FromUri (Name = "foo.bar.text")] string text)
{...}
```

none of which have succeeded.

If I specify a name without dots (i.e. a name without a path), and I use `/?` as separator between path name and resource name, I can retrieve the resource successfully. However, this is not an option (I have to use `?` even though there is a single resource in the request.

How can I modify the C# server to retrieve the resource while maintaining the requested format `pathName?resourceName`?

Answer (score 0):

Paste your `RouteConfig.cs` here. You are using attribute routing so you might need to register those actions by calling this helper function, '`MvcAttributeRoutes()`' from `RouteConfig.cs` file.

Hope it solves!